# How to solve the differential equation $y'=\frac{y}{4 x + 2 y^2 \sqrt{x}}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'=\frac{y}{4 x + 2 y^2 \sqrt{x}}$$

I tried many different methods, but I can't find a general solution.

Comment: What have you tried? Would you be willing to update your question with all the different methods you tried?

Comment: Use MathJax... Not readable.

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$y(x) = \pm \frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{x}}{\sqrt{W\left(2 e^{-\frac{c_1}{2}}
   \sqrt{x}\right)}}$$ where $W$ is the PolyLog function.

Comment: Bernoulli's DE if you consider $x'$ instead of $y'$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve
\begin{gather*}
\boxed{y^{\prime}-\frac{y}{4 x +2 y^{2} \sqrt{x}}=0}
\end{gather*}

This is isobaric ode. Let
\begin{align*}
y&=u \,x^{\frac{1}{4}}
\end{align*}
Then the ode becomes
$$
u^{\prime}\left(x \right) = -\frac{u \left(x \right)^{3}}{4 x \left(u \left(x \right)^{2}+2\right)}
$$
This is seprable. integrating gives
\begin{align*} 
\ln \left(u \right)-\frac{1}{u^{2}} &= -\frac{\ln \left(x \right)}{4}+c_{1}\\
u \,{\mathrm e}^{-\frac{1}{u^{2}}} &= c_{1} x^{-\frac{1}{4}}
\end{align*}

Replacing $u \left(x \right)$ back by $y$ using $u=y x^{-\frac{1}{4}}$ gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{y \,{\mathrm e}^{-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{y^{2}}}}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}}-\frac{c_{1}}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}} &= 0\\
y \,{\mathrm e}^{-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{y^{2}}}-c_{1} &= 0\\
\end{align*}

Solution is implicit. This can be solved for $y$ using special function `LambertW`

$$
y = 
c_{1} \sqrt{2}\, \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{c_{1}^{2} \operatorname{LambertW} \left(\frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{c_{1}^{2}}\right)}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

As @user577215664 commented, start switching variables
$$y'=\frac{y}{4 x + 2 y^2 \sqrt{x}}\implies x'=\frac{4 x + 2 y^2 \sqrt{x}}y$$ Let $$x=z^2\implies y \,z'-2 z =y^2$$
$$z=y^2\, u \implies y\, u'=1$$ whci does not look too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

ok let go

$y'=\frac{y}{4 x + 2 y^2 \sqrt{x}}\implies x'=\frac{4 x + 2 y^2 \sqrt{x}}y$

$x'-\frac{4x}{y}=2y\sqrt{x}$ , bernoulli so
divided by $\sqrt{x}$

$\frac{x'}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{4\sqrt{x}}{y}=2y$

let :$\sqrt{x}=z\implies\frac{x'}{\sqrt{x}}=2z'$

$z'-\frac{2z}{y}=y$ , First order linear

$z=y^{2}(\int y^{-1} dy +c)$ , $z=\sqrt{x}$

$\sqrt{x}=y^{2}(\ln(y)+c)$

$$x=y^{4}(\ln(y)+c)^{2}$$